# Using Thrift with Delphi Win32

Tags: web-services, delphi, thrift, evernote

I'm interested in connecting to the Evernote Service API, which uses Thrift, from a Delphi Win32 app I am developing.  I have done very little work with web services in Delphi, and nothing at all with Thrift.  Where would be the best place to get up to speed w/using Thrift from Delphi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Old Answer Replaced thanks to Leo:**
Thrift has generators for *Delphi*, C++, C#, Erlang, Haskell, Java, Objective C/Cocoa, OCaml, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, and Squeakr

The generators for Thrift can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/compiler/cpp/src/thrift/generate).